# How to make plane geometry lookAt camera using threejs

Tags: javascript, 3d, camera, three.js

I have added sphere and plane geometry to scene when I rotate the camera the plane geometry should look at the
camera, I have used camera.lookAt( plane.position ); this did not work then i tried to use 
plane.quaternion.copy( camera.quaternion ); only 1 plane geometry looked at the camera can someone please help
me how to solve this problem. I have also added the image and code below.

```
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var metrics = context.measureText( cardinal.name );
            var textWidth = metrics.width;
            context.fontSize = '100pt Calibri';
            context.fillStyle = 'red';

            context.fillText(cardinal.name, 0, 50);
            var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas) ;
            texture.needsUpdate = true;
            //var spriteAlignment = new THREE.Vector2(0,0) ;
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffffff, side: THREE.DoubleSide ,map : texture} );
            var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 0.5, 0.3);
            plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            plane.position.set(X_value,0,Z_value);


            //camera.lookAt(X_value,0,Z_value);
            //plane.lookAt(camera.position);
            scene.add(plane);


            }
function animate(spritearray) {

                //sprite.update();
                //spritearray.update();

                for(var j=0; j<spritearray.length; j++){

                    var labelupdate = spritearray[j];
                    labelupdate.update();
                }
                requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
                controls.update();
                renderer.render(scene, camera);


                camera.lookAt( plane.position );

            }
```

Comment: why not to use `THREE.Sprite()` instead of planes?

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling the lookAt function on the plane? `plane.lookAt(camera.position)` ?